# Check if a call was received from the incoming caller in last 20 days

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-twiml

I am writing this in twilio functions, it returns Fail if the caller has called in the last 20 days or Success if the caller has not called in the last 20 days. The function is always returning Fail regardless. Not sure where its messing up.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const client = context.getTwilioClient();
  const callerNumber = event.From;
  const twentyDaysAgo = new Date();
  twentyDaysAgo.setDate(twentyDaysAgo.getDate() - 20);

  client.calls
    .list({
      from: callerNumber,
      startTimeAfter: twentyDaysAgo.toISOString(),
      limit: 1
    })
    .then((calls) => {
      if (calls.length > 0) {
          callback(null,'Fail'); //returns fail as length is >0 so call was received
      } else {
          callback(null,'Success');     //returns null which is success so call was not received
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      callback(err);
    });
};
```

I am writing this in twilio functions, it returns Fail if the caller has called in the last 20 days or Success if the caller has not called in the last 20 days. The function is always returning Fail regardless. Not sure where its messing up.

Comment: make sure you are using the right timezones

Answer (score 0):

maybe you calculate the wrong date, try my code below

```js
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  // new date function
  const MakeDay = (date: Date, num: number): Date => {
      return new Date(date.getTime() + (num * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  }
  // your code
  const client = context.getTwilioClient();
  const callerNumber = event.From;
  const twentyDaysAgo = MakeDay(new Date(), -20); // use new date function

  client.calls
    .list({
      from: callerNumber,
      startTimeAfter: twentyDaysAgo.toISOString(),
      limit: 1
    })
    .then((calls) => {
      if (calls.length > 0) {
          callback(null,'Fail'); //returns fail as length is >0 so call was received
      } else {
          callback(null,'Success');     //returns null which is success so call was not received
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      callback(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: Yes, a little edit to your code did the trick. The working code is below